# Can I run appium inspector through command prompt server

Tags: appium-android

I am getting following error while running server through the command prompt I am strictly said that I should not use the Appium-desktop,[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQnzv.png)

I tried to launch the application without using appium-desktop-client server and starting server in command prompt, with following capabilities
{
"platformName": "Android",
"appium:platformVersion": "13",
"appium:deviceName": "Xiaomi Pad 6",
"appium:appPackage": "com.rs.axis",
"appium:appActivity": "com.rs.axis.MainActivity",
"appium:udid": "e3958a4a"
}
I need to launch app successfully and inspect elements